# I'm getting “content could not be loaded” when loading magnific popup with Apache 2.4.6 - but not Apache 2.2.15

Tags: jquery, apache, magnific-popup

I'm moving our website to newer servers - CentOS 6 -> 7, etc. Most everything is working fine, but I'm stumped on this MagnificPopup issue. The existing servers are running Apache 2.2.15 and the new servers have Apache 2.4.6. Code and included tools are the the same versions.  Are there any known issues that I can work around?

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
        src: rootURL + "/html/"+popupurl
    },
    type: 'ajax',
    removalDelay: 300,
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    callbacks: {
        ajaxContentAdded: function () {
            $('#closepopup').click(function () {    //close popup
                $.magnificPopup.close();
            });

            ...

        }
    }
});
```

The variable popupurl contains an HTML filename that should be displayed.  As I said, works on the old servers, but not the new.  Just get the `The content could not be loaded.` message.

Comment: Have you checked the browser developer tools? I bet you have a CORS error in the console or, at least, some relevant info (status code and response body) in the network pane.

Answer (score 0):

Alvario -- Good thought. There wasn't any errors in the console or the network pane. All showed good and 200 responses.

Got me thinking though and found a typo in the `rootURL` variable. Changed it and fixed the issue. It wasn't CORS, just pathing.  Sometimes it's the obvious that we overlook trying to find a deeper issue.

Thanks!